# clean URLs with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to have clean URLs, here is my code:

```
Options -Multiviews -Indexes +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z\-\_]+)?$ profile.php?q=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /page/error?q=aqw
```

The only issue is that, i can not call a directory, i have to specify the file name, for exemple:

```
<a href="site.com/help">Help</a> //this is not working
<a href="site.com/help/index"></a> //This is working
```

So how can i fix that, thanks

Comment: If you just append `.php` to `/help`, then of course that will only look for a file called `help.php` – and if that doesn’t exist, of course it fails. It’s up to you to specify where such a request should be rewritten to. If you just want it to display the index file for that directory – then _don’t_ rewrite directories in the first place.

Comment: You mean, i need to specify the file name ? there's not a solution ?

Comment: Depends on what exactly you want. If you are OK with using `/help/`, then don’t rewrite for directories at all, and let the `DirectoryIndex` directive take effect. If you insist on using only `/help` (and not having that rewritten to `/help/` by your server automatically), then make a different rule for existing directories, and internally rewrite to the index file explicitly. (Be aware though that using an existing directory without a trailing slash inside the URL might mess up relative paths you use in your documents.)

Comment: what i want: remove slash [direcotories] - remove .php [files] i like to be able to go to site.com/help instead of site.com/help/index

Comment: Well then try it the way I said.

Comment: if i use your way, it will be [directories] site.com/help/ (with a slash) [files] site.com/help/index is this your way ? is there a way to remove the slash here (help/) ?

Comment: Please update your question with how you have tried to implement what I said. (And no, I did not say you should use a trailing slash in your links. But, depending on your server configuration, it might get added automatically via redirect from `/help` to `/help/`. If so, you would have to disable that [if you’re allowed to].)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your rules I think your first rule is redundant that you can remove.

Try this in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

ErrorDocument 404 /error?q=aqw

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: this adds a slash at the end

Comment: Sorry none of my rule is adding/removing slash any where. Can you elaborate further? Do you have some existing rules also?

Comment: site.com/help/file.php -> site.com/help/file yeah it's working in this way, but if i don't specify the file, i mean if it's a directory, it adds a slash, site.com/help/ i would like to be site.com/help (reading index file)

Comment: Oh that is being added by Apache's `mod_dir` module not by these rules. You can use `DirectorySlash Off` to disable that feature but usually it is kept in `On` state as by default Apache loads content from `site.com/help/indexp.php` (if you have `DirectoryIndex index.php` line at the top).

Comment: I DirectoryIndex index.php AND DirectorySlash Off, if i go to site.com/help i get Error 403 it works if i add a slash site.com/help/

Comment: That's why I said `DirectorySlash Off` is not recommended. It is a huge security risk also as it can show content of your directory also if there is no `index.php` inside.

Comment: Change options to `Options -Multiviews +Indexes +FollowSymLinks`

Comment: i changed, but samething

Comment: Don't you think we are now solving totally different problem than what was asked. Trailing slash is done by `mod_dir` Read my comments about `DirectorySlash` being unsafe also.

Comment: Okay, i decided to not remove "/", the updated code is working fine, is that okay for you ?

Comment: Yes this is perfectly fine and safe for your website also. If it all worked out then consider marking the answer as accepted also.

Comment: this is what i had before coming to stackoverflow, nothing changed, but say what, okay, i consider it... it's a gift lol